# Using an older version of Photoshop to save on RAM?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a rather dated laptop (Core i3) so I'm wondering if using Photoshop CS3 or CS4 would be lighter than CS5-6..

I have 4GB of RAM.

Comment: It sounds like most of your performance problems with Photoshop are because you run it within a Virtual Machine.  Photoshop has always been a resource hog.

Answer (score 1):

I have a 2006 MacBook Pro with only 2 Gb RAM (yes, it's still alive and working ;-).

I tried Photoshop CS5 and it run well, but I'm back to CS2. I know, this is a little extreme, that's not Intel ready, but I'm working a little better, I can open another apps while Photoshop is in the background.

I downgraded the VM to a 40-50% and the Cache level to 1, reduced the history to the minnimum (as described in makephotoshopfaster.com) and other tweaks.

I need empty cache each hour or half hour, when the RAM is under 150 Mb, depending if I need to open the browser to search any image o something else.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Core I3 CPU, 4GB ram, Intel 4000 Graphic Card and Photoshop CS6 works fine for template designing. But if you want to work with PS *professionally* you should certainly try old PS versions with this computer configuration.

It is often true that old software needs less resources than new software.

Comment: The thing I run Photoshop also on a VM so I got less resources..

Comment: It's too bad, Try old version of PS.

Comment: although the basic problem is the PSD file I'm working on is made up from many groups of layers.. lighter files are easier